Tableau to power bi Dax conversion
SUM((FIXED DATEPART('quarter', [Calendar Day]), DATEPART('year', [Calendar Day]):SUM(IF DATEPART('quarter', [Calendar Day]) =

DATEPART('quarter', [Current Day MY)-1) and DATEPART('year', [Calendar Day)) DATEPART('year', [Current Day MY]-1) THEN (WORKING DAY YTD] END)))

Please help me to provide the equivalent Dax query for above tableau formula.
I tried below and many other things but values are not matching.
Like below code I tried.
Previous_Quarter_Working_Days :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( YourTable[WORKING_DAY_YTD] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( YourTable ),
        YEAR ( YourTable[Calendar Day] ) = YEAR ( TODAY() ) - 1
            && QUARTER ( YourTable[Calendar Day] ) = QUARTER ( TODAY() ) - 1
    )
)

The output should be 7 because for current quarter(Q2) and year(2024) tha value for working day YTD field is 0,7 so the output should be 7 for sum. But I am getting results in million as it is summing all the value. Please help me to provide the dax query
